# Can I bind data to data-win-options?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winjs

I use the control MicrosoftNSJS.Advertising.AdControl in the ItemTemplate of a ListView.
I would like to bind some datas to the following data-win-options properties : ApplicationId and AdUnitId

The source datas are correctly set and are visible in my item template, I can display them with an h2 + a classic data-win-bind on innerText property

Ads are displayed correctly if I put directly static IDs in html code but these IDs need to be loaded from a config file...

Is it possible ? Thanks

If it's not possible, can I modify directly the item template in the JS code before to be injected in the listview ?

Answer (score 3):

Come to find out this is possible (I was trying to do something similar)

The syntax for the control properties must be prefixed with winControl.

Example (I'm setting the application id here but binding the html element's className and the ad control's adUnitId)

```
<div id="adItemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div data-win-bind="className:css; winControl.adUnitId: adUnitId"
        data-win-control="MicrosoftNSJS.Advertising.AdControl"
        data-win-options="{ applicationId: 'd25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab'}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show an example of how this works on the actual data-win-options attribute. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to perform this without real binding, by using the itemTemplateSelector function like this :

```
function itemTemplateSelector(itemPromise) 
{
   return itemPromise.then(function (item) 
   { 
    if (item.type == "ad")
    {
        var template = _$(".adTemplate").winControl.render(item, null);

        // Access to the AdControl through the DOM
        var adControl = template._value.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].winControl;

        // Set options that are specified in the item
        WinJS.UI.setOptions(adControl, { applicationId: item.AdAppId, adUnitId: item.AdUnitId });

        return template;
    }
    else
    {
        return _$(".itemTemplate").winControl.render(item, null);
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in ratings:

```
 <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Rating" data-win-options="{averageRating: 3.4, onchange: basics.changeRating}"></div>
```

I bind it via winControl:

```
 <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Rating" data-win-bind="winControl.averageRating: myrating" data-win-options="{onchange: basics.changeRating}"></div>
```

It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div data-win-bind="this['data-list_item_index']:id WinJS.Binding.setAttribute" >
```